# UIScrollViews overlapping

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I'm building a simple app where you can describe your look with a paper doll kinda tool. [Check out this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6dyo.png) 
The plan was to have 4 horizontal scrollviews: one for hairstyle, second for facial hair, 3d for tops, 4th for bottoms. I've just realized that scrollviews will overlap. E.g. bottom part of long hair overlaps with a scrollview for facial hair as well as with scrollview for tops. Is it ok and technically possible to overlap scrollviews? Say bottom half of scrollview for long hair is under top half of facial hair scrollview.  I'm going to play with that anyway but perhaps someone some experience with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really want the scrollviews overlapping because of scrolling and touches I don't think but you can let the contents escape the bounds of the view it is in or even the scrollview to give it the appearance that it overlaps. The biggest issue I see is that you might have to change the zposition of the scrollview or subviews to make long hair on top or tucked in short underneath and such.

I would recommend UICollectionViews scrolling horizontally.  Then make sure to uncheck cliptobounds on the collection view and any cells.  Add an image view make sure you uncheck clipstobounds.  Make it align top.  (You will need to adjust some images on the fly and increase or decrease size to make it look good but that is another question).  The z index is meaning bring collection views to the front based on which should overlap or not.  Attached is a video of exactly what I talked about and a screenshot of the storyboard.  The only other thing I did in the video was to bring subviews to the front like so

```
extension UICollectionView{
open override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)     {
    superview!.bringSubview(toFront: self)
  }
}
```

Although that would not be how I would do this in production. I would probably animate it.

[image: story]

You can see that the images come down quite a bit but what you could do is redraw them to smaller based on the size of the collection view so they don't come down so much and ones that are supposed to stay in their area you could redraw to be the exact size of the cell or change the content mode of the image view on the fly

Video [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8p7W9MDCkTaa0xUcmE4TWM2eE0)

I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: So I gave it a try. Overlapping of two different scrollviews is not possible – you get one scrollview inside of another one which is funny but does not make any sense. Keeping element partially on a scrollview partially outside of it ("escaping the bounds of the scrollview") also is not an option. If scrollview is smaller than an element it serves as a container – you can see only part of this element. Didn't quite understand what you mean in the last sentence. Could you describe?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8p7W9MDCkTaa0xUcmE4TWM2eE0 my method described above

Comment: Interesting! I'll play with it tomorrow. Thank you, appreciate it